# How many miles will Jane be from her starting point if she walks north for $3$ miles, turns $45^\circ$ to the right, then walks another $4$ miles?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If Jane walks north for $3$ miles, turns $45^\circ$ to the right, and then walks another $4$ miles, how many miles will Jane be from her starting point? Give your answer as a decimal rounded to the nearest hundredth. (You may use a calculator to compute the approximation.)

So I used the law of cosines to get $2.83$ as my final answer. But, it said I was wrong so please explain if my math is wrong.
$$n^2 = 3^2+4^2 - 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot \cos(45^\circ)$$
Thanks for any help!!

Comment: 2.83 can’t possibly be right since Jane is still moving away from the starting point after turning. That 45° is measured on the outside of the triangle. You want the complementary angle.

Comment: Write $\cos (135 ^\circ )$ and it will be fine

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I suggest you change your title..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jane turned $45°$.  That is the *exterior* angle at the vertex of the triangle.  What appears in the Law of Cosines is the *interior* angle, supplementary to the exterior one and here equal to $135°$.  So put $\cos(135°)$ into the expression and you're good.

[image: distance_traveled_diagram]

Comment: I added a diagram to illustrate your solution.  If you object, delete it.